# how do i close a frame yet open a new frame?

Tags: java, swing

how do i close a frame yet open a new frame?

i have a frame, (help)

when i click on my menu item 
i want to open (mainForm)
exit from help.

`new mainForm().setVisible(true);
System.exit(0);`

i know this closes the whole program however how do i get it to only close the current frame

thanks

Comment: maybe you need to post your entire code that refers to your 'help' frame

Comment: @Tuffy- from your comment in extraneon, its unsure of what your code is actually doing from 'main' and 'help', so could you post code for those created frames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you no longer want to use the frame you could use `frame.dispose()`

If you just want to hide it use `frame.setVisible(false)`.

If you extended a Frame and are trying to close it from within use `this.dispose` or `this.setVisible(false)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should rethink your requirments. For the user, it would be best to have both the program and the help window visible at the same time. Closing the main window when showing the help screen and vice versa is *really, really bad* for usability - you shouldn't do it. We've had window-based GUIs for almost 30 years now - showing several windows on screen at the same time is what they're for!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should hide the frame you do not wish shown with setVisible(false). System.exit(0) stops the JVM ending the entire program.

In short, the semantics of setVisible has nothing to do with starting / stopping the application.

If you want to start an entire new application you'd have to look at Runtime.exec(). I don't really know if you can close the parent process (the Help application) with exit() though.

Comment: i think i may have confused you.

here is the scenario.

i am in help i click on the menu bar where it says main. when main is clicked i want it to show main and hide help.

if i set that to false it will also hide main

Comment: there is no exit() method for a Frame. 'exit' is for the entire system

Comment: I know. I was wondering whether you can start a new process from within the JVM, and then close the current process while not killing the newly started process also.

Comment: yes you can do that if their both independently created processes

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you created your frame as so:

```
 JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Radio Notes");
//show Frame
mainframe.setVisible(true);
//close the frame  
mainframe.dispose();
```

Comment: it's not main frame iam trying to get rid of, its help. when i do help.dispose(); it doesn't work

Comment: mainframe was just an example of a created frame, if you named the frame help then yes help.dispose will close it; for example if you created a frame: JFrame help= new JFrame("help"); then help.dispose() will close it

Answer (score 0):

try setting the default close operation for the JFrame like so.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then implement a [WindowListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) that performs the actions you want when a window closing event is fired.